# Cannot able to update chef run_list

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

I have cookbook name *sample* and under recipes I have two recipes namely `default.rb` and `execute.rb`. When I give run_list as `recipe[sample]`, it is working well. It is basically taking `default.rb`. How can I add both the recipes to run_list.

I tried `recipe[sample::default],recipe[sample::execute]`, but it is not working.

Comment: What command are you trying to specify the run list? I assume `knife run list set nodename recipe[sample::default],recipe[sample::execute]`, right?

Comment: I used 'knife node edit node-name'.

Comment: When using `knife node edit` make sure your data is valid JSON, the formatting is important.

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote the run list parameter for the knife command:

```
knife run list set nodename "recipe[sample::default],recipe[sample::execute]"
```

Another possibility is to use `knife node run list add`:

```
knife run list add nodename "recipe[sample::execute]"
```